# NodeJS NPM can't install express, I've tried the solutions on SO

Tags: node.js, npm

So today I'm trying to install express and I keep getting this error:

```
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.8.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
```

I've uninstalled Node and reinstalled it and it still says the same thing. I've updated everything and still it outputs the same error.

Comment: What do you get when you run: ```node -v```

Comment: Update Node.js.  You're running a very old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repository is provided on the [Installing NodeJS guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os) which includes the latest version of NodeJS. Try the following to uninstall the current version of node you have installed and install the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

This should install both npm and nodejs

Comment: I'm assuming that's the error received after reinstalling nodejs using the commands above? If so please run the two commands
`node -v` and `npm -v`
and post the output

Comment: have you tried making an empty directory in your home folder and running `npm install express` inside that directory to see if it works. I can see you are working out of /var/www, could it be permission related issues? Other than that, I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Sounds like you don't have write permissions in /var/www. Glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed newest node or NPM ?

```
sudo apt-get install npm
npm install -g express
```

to make your express project:

```
express myapp
```

Here is  [the complete instructions](http://teknosains.com/i/tutorial-install-nodejs-npm-and-express-in-ubuntu-1204)